# Remove lines in "file 1" which contains a series of numbers from list in "file 2"

Tags: notepad++

I have two TXT files. First one contains 10.000s hyperlinks which I need to download. Second one contains series of numbers (name of files) which I successfully download. BUT, some of files not downloaded. Need way to delete hyperlinks (lines) from "file 1" which contain series of numbers from second file so I dont redownload them. Need clean file 1 with hyperlinks which I need to download again because macro recorder skip them.

Example file 1:

```
https://www.shutterstock.com/download/confirm/70023262?id=70023262&size=huge_jpg&src=download_history
https://www.shutterstock.com/download/confirm/61707421?id=61707421&size=huge_jpg&src=download_history
https://www.shutterstock.com/download/confirm/72736375?id=72736375&size=vector_eps&src=download_history
https://www.shutterstock.com/download/confirm/12755167?id=12755167&size=vector_eps&src=download_history
https://www.shutterstock.com/download/confirm/75060223?id=75060223&size=huge_jpg&src=download_history
```

Example file 2:

```
70023262
61707421
72736375
```

First 3 is downloaded ok and this 3 lines need to be removed from "file 1". Last two lines need to stay because I need to redownload it again.

Compare plugin. But how to copy added lines, green with + sign?
[Compare plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh1g9.png)

Comment: This is not a job for Notepad++, it looks like a programming problem. What have you tried?

Comment: Compare plugin. But how to copy added lines, green with + sign? Compare plugin. See picture "compare plugin"

Comment: Write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

solution

1. In notepad++ I separate with tab number from rest in 3 columns

```
    https://www.shutterstock.com/download/confirm/  218688439   ?id=218688439&size=huge_jpg&src=download_history
    https://www.shutterstock.com/download/confirm/  572805157   ?id=572805157&size=huge_jpg&src=download_history
    https://www.shutterstock.com/download/confirm/  68777392    ?id=68777392&size=huge_jpg&src=download_history
    https://www.shutterstock.com/download/confirm/  119794933   ?id=119794933&size=huge_jpg&src=download_history
```

2. In excel paste in column B at top list of numbers from "file 2".
3. In excel paste at bottom list from step 1 in column a-c.
4. Select column B and choose in excel menu data/remove duplicates, select option "expand selection..." and choose column b in dialog. that is. At bottom will be rest of hyperlinks, which i need to merge column a+b+c.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure you have a copy of the files.

To save the way via Excel I suggest a solution for Notepad++. So, let’s suppose that you have a `file-1.txt` with some of URL records and a smaller `file-2.txt` with the ID as shown in your question above. You need to bookmark all the record of `file-1.txt` that have a substring from `file-2.txt`.

Please note the name of the text file is important for processing in the correct order as described below.

So, follow the steps below (don't be scared, it's easy once you've done it.):

- First open file `file-2.txt` in Notepad++
- Select all the contents of `file-2.txt` ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> )
- Save to clipboard ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> )
- Open your second file `file-1.txt`
- At the end of `file-1.txt` add a new line with many e.g. colons :::::: (or %, @, etc.) not present in both files, which will be like a delimiter between the two files!
- Append the contents of the clipboard at the end of `file-1.txt` after the line :::::: ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> )
- Go back to very beginning of the present `file-1.txt`( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pos1</kbd>  )
- Open the Find dialog ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> )
- Select the Mark tab
- Check the Bookmark line option
- Select the Regular expression search mode
- Find what: `([0-9]{8,8})(?=(?s).*:::::.*?\1)`
- Click on the Mark All button

All the lines, of `file-1.txt` with a matching substring located after the line `::::::`, (from  `file-2.txt`) are bookmarked.

Move to line `::::::` and delete all the appended lines to the end of the file. Finally, save the new state, with all the bookmarks OR delete these lines for your needs before saving by:

> Search > Bookmark > Remove Bookmarked Lines